# Uncaught TypeError: modal.getInstance is not a function error

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a login system for my web app and I have a sign up modal pop up so the user can sign up. After the user signs in and the credentials are accepted, I am trying to close the modal and reset the signup form after the user submits it. For some reason I am getting the error: Uncaught TypeError: modal.getInstance is not a function

I was wondering if anyone knows the issue with my getInstance statement.

Here is the code:

```
// signup
const signupForm = document.querySelector('#signUp-form');
signupForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  // get user info
  const email = signupForm['signUp-email'].value;
  const password = signupForm['signUp-password'].value;

  // sign up the user
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(cred => {
    console.log(cred.user);
    // close the signup modal & reset form
    const myModal = document.querySelector('#subscribe-Modal');
    modal.getInstance(myModal).hide();
    signupForm.reset();
  });
});
```

Here is code for the modal object

```
  <div id="subscribe-Modal" class="modal">

                                <!-- Modal content -->
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                <span class="close">&times;</span>
```

Comment: You are referring to `modal` but no where in the provided code do you have any reference to creating `modal`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide your modal you can use `$('#subscribe-Modal').modal('hide')`

Comment: It is still saying there is an error with the getInstance because it is not a function

Comment: That got rid of the error but it still didn't close the modal for some reason.